# PHP-MySQL: Returning Query as Array index name and value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
------------
|animal|legs|
------------
| cat     4 |
| chicken 2 |
```

Is it possible to return an array in PHP with animals as its index name and legs as its values without fetching one by one as in mysqli_fetch_all ?

```
$result[cat]=4
$result[chicken]=2.
```

I tried

```
$q = mysqli_fetch_all($q);
$array=array_combine($q2[0], $q2[1]);
```

but it does not give me the output that I wanted.

Comment: Show the code you have and the desired output.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a conventional loop?

Comment: Suppose I have:
$result= mysqli_query($con,"select animal, leg from aTable");
My desired output is as in the question:
$result[cat]=4
$result[chicken]=2
However I try to avoid using loop [e.g. using fetch all].
The problem is on how do I get an array with "animal" as the array index and "legs" as the array value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

```
$dic = $db->getIndCol("animal","SELECT * FROM animals");
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not OOP kind of person.
How is that translated in procedural style ?

Comment: this cannot be translated to procedural style. Yet there is nothing complex with OOP when you need only use it, not write your own. It is exactly the same procedure, but with `$var->`. just call it this way and you don't need to know anything else

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_all($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $result[$row['animal']] = $row['legs'];
}
```

Remember to use apostrophes around strings in array labels in this way, as 'cat' or 'chicken'.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to avoid mysql_fetch_array and prefer fetch_all since it's faster.

Comment: Edited with mysqli_fetch_all